# Trying to implement Time table in grails

Tags: grails

I'm working on university project and it has many domains like Course,department,Faculty etc.I want to make a time-table for a student on semester basis. So Is there any plugin available likewise we have for calender?

Comment: Most likely there isn't a plugin, did you search grails.org? Your BL will probably need to be written by you I'm afraid.

Comment: It seems like you're asking for a plugin which does what your application should. :) Anyway, after a fast search I couldn't find anyone, maybe you could be the first to release one (even if I still can't get what this plugin should do - a plugin should solve a generic problem and I can't which yours is).

Comment: Do you need UI or a domain class structure? What is the exact structure of the time-table? Is this a homework?

Comment: @VictorSergienko : I need a UI. Basically what we see in colleges. A student time table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might (or might not) benefit from using FullCalendar (a JavaScript-based solution similar to Google Calendar). There is a plugin available for it here:

http://grails.org/plugin/full-calendar

There is also some blog posts about integrating FullCalendar in Grails here:

http://www.craigburke.com/blog/2012/02/09/creating-google-calendar-in-grails-part-1-the-model/